# Unable to understand an inequality in an application of the pumping lemma for context-free languages

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

**The problem**

Prove that the language

$\qquad L = \{a^n b^j \mid n = j^2\}$

is not context free using pumping lemma.

**Approach taken by the [book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Cgooanwdo9AC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)**

To prove such statements, the book takes the approach of a game played against an opponent who strives to fail our effort to prove that the language is not context free. The steps involved in the game are as follows:

- The opponent chooses m such that for all w $\in$ L, |w| >= m
- We choose the string w
- The opponent decomposes w in uvxyz such that |vxy| <= m and |vy| >= 1
- We pump v and y i-times to get the string uv$^i$xy$^i$z.

  Now, if for **any** i = 0,1,2,...

  uv$^i$xy$^i$z $\notin$ L

  the language L is not context free.

**The solution to the above problem**

- Opponent chooses m
- We choose w = a$^{m^2}$b$^m$
- The opponent decomposes w in uvxyz as follows:

  [image]
- Pumping v and y i-times yields string with m$^2$+(i-1)k$_1$ a's and m+(i-1)k$_2$ b's.
- If opponent takes k$_1$ $\ne$ 0 and k$_2$ $\ne$ 0, we can take i = 0, such that

  (m-k$_2$)$^2 \leq$  (m-1)$^2$             ... since k$_2\ne$ 0 making minimum value of k$_2$ is 1

  = m$^2$-2m+1

  **< m$^2$ - k$_1$**

  **Q.** ***This last line I did not understand. How is -2m+1 < -k$_1$? Especially because I can find the below decomposition uvxyz for which -2m+1 > -k$_1$.***

[image]

***I must be missing some stupid algebra here.***

The solution further continues saying that the pumped resultant string does not belong to L.

- Similar argument can be done if user select k$_1$ = 0 and k$_2$ $\ne$ 0  or k$_1$ $\ne$ 0 and k$_2$ = 0

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. Not only is it lazy, it also makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and maths (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: @Raphael here u go. It took huge efforts to write what that image was to imply using LaTeX. I could have used that time for something else.

Comment: Be careful with the attitude there; you are asking people to spend time on your problem instead of using that time for something else. Thanks for the edit, though.

Comment: I am lately fade up by my questions not getting answered on cs.stackexchange. I tried putting my questions well, but for three questions they keep downvoting my questions not even single comment for downvote, forget answering it. I eventually end up deleting my own question. So yess lately I am having bad experience with community at cs.stackexchange :\ , dont know thats just me. On stackoverflow I have excellent experience. Doesnt look the same here.

Comment: I'm sure you understand that nobody is entitled to an answer here; maybe someone out of the crowd finds the question interesting or valuable enough, maybe not. It's nothing personal. I suggest you check out some upvoted questions and see what they do different from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pumping Lemma requires $|vxy| \le m$ so that the pumped parts are of bounded length. Thus $k_1+k_2\le m$. With this it is easy.

As $k_2 \neq 0$, we must have $k_1<m$. Also $m>0$ as the pumping constant must be positive (but in fact we can assume it to be as large as we want, of course).

Now $2m-1 \ge m > k_1$.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

$m-k_2$ is the number of $b$'s in the pumped word, let us call it $w'$. In order for $w'$ to be in the language, the number of $a$'s has to be $(m-k_2)^2$. Depending on the chosen $k_2$, this is *at most* $(m-1)^2 = m^2-2m+1$. The actual number of $a$'s, however, is $m^2 - k_1$ and this is truly greater than $m^2-2m+1$. Hence, the pumped word $w'$ is not part of the language.

Comment: Hey please check the new diagram I added to the original quesstion. I still dont understand how m$^2$-k$_1$ is truly greater than m$^2$-2m+1

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use [Parikh's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh's_theorem) to prove that your language is not context-free. Indeed the Parikh image of your language is by construction the subset
$
 \{ (j^2, j) \mid j \in \mathbb{N} \}
$
of $\mathbb{N}^2$. It is now easy to see that this set is not semi-linear and therefore your language is not context-free.